# Displaying Gsub input with Spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub, string-substitution

I have a :name attribute which i use for linking to User's Show Profile.

I needed the storing in the Database to be without Spacing so i used Gsub.

```
def name=(value)
        write_attribute(:name, value.gsub(/\s+/, ""))
end
```

But upon Displaying that value again on some Show Page via

```
<%= link_to @show.name, @show %>
```

the name get's displayed without Spaces.

I Tried

```
raw(@show.name)
```

but this didn't worked either.

**How do i maintain** the un-spaced in the link but showing it with spaces on any page ?

My Model:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    validates :announcement, length: { maximum: 250 }

    # Show Cover
    has_attached_file :cover, styles: { show_cover: "870x150#"}
    validates_attachment :cover,
                                             content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg',
                                                                                                            'image/png'] },
                                             size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }


    def to_param
        name
    end

    def name=(value)
        write_attribute(:name, value.gsub(/\s+/, ""))
    end

end
```

Comment: That is not going to be accurate/possible.  One solution I can suggest is to split out the name attribute to say "first_name, middle_name, last_name, suffix" and so on.

Comment: This input is not about the Actual Name of the User, but the :username. For the link and Show Name (Every user has a Show). Is there any other possibility for doing this, or should i use another method (not gsub)

Comment: Are you also storing the raw name in some other column?  May be a better solution would be to have two different columns, one for name(with spaces) and another for username(without spaces).

Comment: How can i store from one Input Field, Two different entries? if that's possible, mid answering with that ? :)

Comment: Sure, there are a couple of solutions.  Can you tell me where else this username can be used other than `link_to`?

Comment: I Display it mainly. On a variety of controllers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36210/discussion-between-vinodadhikary-and-the-mini-john)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Display it mainly. On a variety of controllers.

If it's just for display, don't strip out spaces.  Store the actual name, then define a method `username` which removes spaces from name.

Something like following should work:

```
# Model
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Returns name removing all spaces
    def username
      self.name.gsub(/\s+/, "")
    end

    # Remove just the leading and trailing white spaces
    def name=(value)
        write_attribute(:name, value.strip)
    end
end
```

Then in your controller(s):

```
<%= link_to @show.username, @show %>
```

**Update:**

After having a chat with OP, understood that he is using `to_param` method in `Show` model which returned `username` (i.e. `name` with all spaces removed).  This caused a problem in `find` method because the value in DB included spaces and the value being searched for did not have any spaces, as a result of which a DB specific function needed to be used e.g. `where("replace(name, ' ', '') = ?", user_name)` in case of MySQL.  Since the OP is using different databases in development and production, i.e. SQLite in development and PG in production.  So, instead of crafting a solution that worked across different databases, recommended OP to use [FriendlyId gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Comment: It did not work.. When i edit the Profile and press F5 the name gets changed to nospaces automatically. That means that it got stored with no spaces right? Although i tried your code, it did not work :(

Comment: Can you explain the did not work part?  What's not working?  Are you allowing edit of username?

Comment: I'm getting errors on the useraname part OR the link contains the name WITH spaces (%20).. That's my Model -> https://gist.github.com/Theminijohn/6336159 . Can you give it a look?. No i'm not allowing username Changes.

Answer (score 1):

If spaces are the problem, why not convert them to underscores and then use a helper to display that?

```
def name=(value)
  write_attribute(:name, value.gsub(/\s+/, "_"))
end
```

You could then create a helper method that's just for printing/displaying the name.

- Create a `app/helpers/users_helper.rb`
- Put something like this in that helper:

  ```
  module UsersHelper
    def pretty_name(user)
      user.name.gsub('_', ' ')
    end
  end
  ```
- In your view you could call it by doing something like: `<%= pretty_name(@user) %>`

If using a delimiter in the name field is not an option, then you should consider modifying the `users` table to have `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, etc

Comment: A Delimiter is unfortunately not an option. The @show.name is actually the "Show Name" (A User has a Show). Has nothing to do with names. Isn't there any other option do Display it without spaces?

Comment: Sorry but i guess I'm confused now. You have edited the question's instance variable names and it totally changes everything.  Maybe consider rewriting this question and providing detail about exactly what you want as output, why, and the code you have written already. The model relationships would be helpful as well because i had no idea "show" was a model and not the common controller action/view `show`.

Comment: No you are right, Show is a controller. Not like the show action, like a TV SHOW controller :)